# IE z-index bug doesn't properly display divs

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have two divs one inside another, i would like to overlap one div with other and also use css idnex, but ie doesn't let me do this, is there some kind of workaround?

**Please view this code in IE since it works in other browsers.**

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkDCX/1/

And the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="button"></div>
<div>


body{
    margin:50px;
}

.container{
    position:relative;
    width:410px;
    height: 300px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#daf5fd', endColorstr='#0dbcf5');
    z-index:22;
}

.button{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:2px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    right:-10px;
    top:-10px;
    background:black;
    z-index:11;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that the filter you added doesnt work at all only in IE so when you see the style in other browsers they dont recognize it at all.

UPDATE:

Would this worked out for you?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="but"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background"></div>
<div>

<style>
body{
    margin:50px;
}

.container{
    position:fixed;
    width:410px;
    height:300px;    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;   
}

.container .background{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#daf5fd', endColorstr='#0dbcf5');
    z-index: 50;
}

.container .button{
    position:absolute;
    width:410px;   
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    z-index: 100;  
} 

.container .but{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:black;
    right:-10px;
    top:-10px;
    border:2px solid black;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: i know that it works only in ie i didn't add css for other browsers because i didn't wanted to flood the code. and the issue is that it doesn't work in ie, i think you should see how the half od the black box get's cut off?

Comment: Yes I do see that, thats because you did the .button div right and top -10

Comment: well i did that on purpose, and in all other major browsers it works fine

Comment: So just take off the filter will everything be okay, I dont mind it will work with that filter so far.

Comment: that filter is there for a reason i need to get that gradient background, if you know any more css rules which can do that i would like to see them, ofcourse it has to work in IE

Comment: I put some example please have a look on it.

Comment: where did i say that i need a whole background to have gradient background... seriously?

Comment: oh sorry i didn't saw that you updated the code, it seems to be working, i will try to update code in my website tomorrow if it works i'll accept your answer, thank you